# Mac OS X Leopard: Shutdown Command?

Tags: mac-osx, osx-leopard

Is this correct command to shutdown Leopard after 60min?

**`sudo shutdown -h 60`**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct usage from the command line for shutting down Mac OS after 60 minutes is:

```
sudo shutdown -h +60
```

That is not the method that Apple recommends using, though it is probably the best way on a headless server.  (***Update: See comment and link from @radius - the use of shutdown is recommended by Apple's server CLI admin guide***).  From the [Command Line Junkies Guide to Mac OS X](http://missionitgroup.com/blog/?p=1234) (the site is out of date but the reference to using osascript is current):

> Rebooting and Shutting Down
>
> Although you can reboot or shut down
>   Mac OS X systems via the traditional
>   halt, reboot and shutdown commands,
>   the Apple-recommended way of turning
>   off the computer remotely is to send
>   the Finder an Apple Event. This can be
>   accomplished using the osascript
>   command to run an AppleScript:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to shut down'
```

or

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to restart'
```

> Of course, this will only work if
>   there's a user logged in, which will
>   typically not be the case with, say,
>   headless servers, in which case you
>   should be able to use traditional UNIX
>   commands without negative
>   consequences.

Comment: Apple server CLI admin guide (http://images.apple.com/server/macosx/docs/Command_Line_Admin_v10.5.pdf) recommand shutdown/restart commands, so it's totaly OK

Comment: The problem with the shutdown approach is that it kills all running GUI apps, without the option to save the data like with the osascript approach. On a server, this should be OK, but on a workstation, it might be a problem. Still, I use shutdown most of the time, because it is way faster if you have many applications open.